# Extract Complex String Inside Parentheses in Linux Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to extract the string like below via the Linux bash tools:

```
XXAAGGHH (XXXXX) ERRTYTUUUI
AAAAAAAA ( %%))XX) $@@$&%^&&
AADDDDD$ (.SD F@* @) *$%^^&^&&&
AA^@%%^^ ()[))DS((]) RTTYUU
```

The extracted resolution should be:

```
XXXXX
  %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

unfortunately, I could not adopt substr for the string lengthes are not fixed.
Inside the parentheses, there may be the parentheses(maybe unbalanced), space or tab (actually, those are garbled from UTF-8 but local system could display  ascii only.)

The patten for my usage is 
" (" : space + left parentheses for left boundary.
" )" : space + right parentheses for right boundary.

I have tried awk, sed and grep, but I got fail.

Could you  give me a hint ? thank you.

Comment: How many of these patterns do you have per line? Just one, or could there be several of them?

Comment: homework assignment?

Comment: Not homework, I want to organize tcpdump data from wireless monitor.

Comment: Do any of the existing answers solve your problem? If so, please indicate so with the checkmark, or else let us know what's missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`sed` only solution:

```
sed 's/.* (\(.*\)) .*/\1/g'
```

Example:

```
sed 's/.* (\(.*\)) .*/\1/g' myInput.txt 
XXXXX
 %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Eo '\(.+\)' input | sed 's/^.//; s/.$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that for figuring out the pattern, simply echoing a sample is an easy way to develop the solution, that's often how I do it. This also lets anyone else try it on their console without having to create the file.

Gawk only solution:

```
echo 'XXAAGGHH (XXXXX) ERRTYTUUUI
AAAAAAAA ( %%))XX) $@@$&%^&&
AADDDDD$ (.SD F@* @) *$%^^&^&&&
AA^@%%^^ ()[))DS((]) RTTYUU' | gawk '{r=gensub(/^[^(]*\((.*)\)[^)]*$/,"\\1","g",$0);print r}'
XXXXX
 %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

awk only solution:

```
echo 'XXAAGGHH (XXXXX) ERRTYTUUUI
AAAAAAAA ( %%))XX) $@@$&%^&&
AADDDDD$ (.SD F@* @) *$%^^&^&&&
AA^@%%^^ ()[))DS((]) RTTYUU' | awk '{gsub(/^[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*$/,"",$0);print $0}'
XXXXX
 %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

sed only solution:

```
echo 'XXAAGGHH (XXXXX) ERRTYTUUUI
AAAAAAAA ( %%))XX) $@@$&%^&&
AADDDDD$ (.SD F@* @) *$%^^&^&&&
AA^@%%^^ ()[))DS((]) RTTYUU' | sed -r 's/^[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*$//g'
XXXXX
 %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

or for file:

```
gawk '{r=gensub(/^[^(]*\((.*)\)[^)]*$/,"\\1","g",$0);print r}' input_file
# OR
awk '{gsub(/^[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*$/,"",$0);print $0}' input_file
# OR
sed -r 's/^[^(]*\(|\)[^)]*$//g'  input_file
# all output:
XXXXX
 %%))XX
.SD F@* @
)[))DS((]
```

It's a very poor idea to try to learn in this way however, there's simply no substitute for pounding your head against regular expressions to figure it out yourself, otherwise you'll never actually learn them. And in my opinion, few things are more valuable to learn long term than regular expressions in programming.

These rules are simple: take everything that is a not a ( that starts the line, and then the first (, and ignore or delete it, then take everything that is not a ) plus the last ) that ends the line and ignore or delete that. You'll note in the answers given there's two options in this case, slice off the beginning and end of the line to give the desired result, or grab the desired result by ignoring the beginning and end of the line, then and print the result.

Note that once you have the pattern, it's not that important what language or tool you use to implement it.

Comment: Thank you, The same require for satisfaction is very easy by C, Java, python or Fortran : if( ')'== *ptr  && ' '== *(ptr + 1)), but shell tools are not so flexible for controlling index...from my perspective